# Confused about 'extern' and 'static extern' storage classes in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, extern

I read over a few articles about this, and am taking a few introductory courses to C++ concurrently. All of the courses I am taking and these articles just don't help me understand how to implement the `extern` and `static extern` storage class. I don't feel comfortable moving on until I really have a grasp on this, even though what I am seeing from other programmers is that they do not use these storage classes, but use inheritance from a header file and local `static` storage class to use a static variable in a function. Both of those instances I can do. I figured out how to use the `static` storage class both within the same source file and also by inheriting the static variable from an inherited source file.

I keep getting linker and / or compiler errors.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with C++11, and have CodeDroid in Android with C++98.

Will someone please teach me how to use the `extern` and `static extern` storage classes without linker and compiler errors?

For example, say I had one.cpp and two.cpp. Say I have an `int main()` function in one.cpp. Say I want to demonstrate outputting the value of an `extern` int in the `main()` function. And, say I have a void function called `extFuncExample()` declared and defined in one.cpp, and also want to output its value there.

A course I am taking has `extern` and `static extern` as two different storage classes. So, if you would be so kind as to break this down to me, so I can output these values without compiler and linker errors.

Thank you so much!

one.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Two.cpp"


    int main()
    {
        extern int global_int;
        std::cout << "global_int = " << global_int << '\n';

        return 0;
    }
```

two.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>

    int global_int = 100;
```

This, I found works. I was including `#include "two.cpp"` in one.cpp and also using the `extern` storage class which was causing the issues. Removed `#include "two.cpp"` and it worked!

Comment: Since you mention both `static` *and* `extern` I assume you mean in the global scope (and not in a class or inside a function)? Perhaps you can show us an example of code that is giving you errors, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And then also please show the actual errors you get.

Comment: There's no `static extern` storage class.

Comment: @n.m well then that course needs to go in the trash LOL Thanks

Comment: @host_255, yes it does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay, I did something I didn't do before, because it wasn't deliberately explained to me but now makes sense. I was including "two.cpp" in "one.cpp", and also defining it in "two.cpp", declaring it in `int main()` of "one.cpp" then outputting it. So, I got LNK2005 and LNK1169. This time, I removed the `#include "two.cpp"` and the linker errors went away. I think this is because including the "two.cpp" as and using the `extern` storage class caused a sort of double-declaration. Is that accurate?

Comment: Without seeing the errors, then yes probably. You should generally not include a source file into another source file, only include header files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the advice. If you want to answer this question, I'd be happy to give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++ there is a difference between a (forwards) declaration and a definition of symbols. `extern` is used to forwards declare the existence of a symbol which is external to the translation unit, that is: to 'import' symbol from "somewhere" and "make it visible" to the code being compiled. At link time the references to `external` symbols are resolved.

Effectively `extern` is a way to instruct the compiler/toolchain that it should not expect to find the symbol definition among the code being compiled, but instead should look in the libraries being linked against to find it. The linker will not bother to do so for symbols that aren't declared `extern`.

Apart from that, there is a somewhat common mistake that people make with `extern`: to use it to declare a global variable and also define it inside a header. For example:

```
// some header.h
extern int my_global = 40; // = 40 makes this wrong.
```

Then they proceed to include it multiple times in different translation units (source files):

```
// file1.c{pp}
#include "header.h"

// file2.c{pp}
#include "header.h"
```

At this point you have introduced multiple definitions for the same symbol in your program because `#include` simply copies the contents of the header verbatim into the context at which the `#include` is performed. The compiler will still compile the code, but the linker will refuse to link it because of the multiple definition error.